# WordPress insert IP address as post meta using PHP and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, ip, post-meta

I'm using AJAX, why I can't insert IP address as post meta `$User_IP = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];` it always insert the database like this `::1`?

My code:

```
function setFilmLikeUser($postID) {

    $count_key = 'add_film_like_user';

    $count     = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);        

    $User_IP   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // Get User IP

    if($count==''){            

        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $User_IP);

    }else{

        if ($count == $User_IP){
            echo "the ip has found before";
        }

        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $User_IP);
    }
}

setFilmLikeUser($Film_ID); // To Start The Action
```

It should be **127.0.0.1** into database but inserted like this **::1**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It should be 127.0.0.1 into database but inserted like this ::1

**::1**  is correct for localhost under IPV6.

Your server is using IPV6 (good) and/or you have this entry in your hosts file `::1   localhost`. "**::1**" is the IPV6 equivalent of IPV4 **127.0.0.1** - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution